# output/rendered text can not be seen in source code

Tags: facebook, scraper, plagiarism-detection

As all Facebook social plugins have this feature;

Your Facebook name can be seen on the web page but when you look up in the source code you can not see Facebook name.

So I need to know why and how?

This feature may be used in order to avoid plagiarism / text content parsers.

Example:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Name of Facebook users do not exist in source code.

Please kindly enlighten me in details thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Sure the names do exist, they're in the iFrame content. You can see the data coming to your browser on the network traffic tab of the developer tools.

Comment: thanks. so using iframe may prevent us from the content thieves.

Comment: No it wont.  You can get to it, I can get to it, your browser can get to it, anyone can get to it.